# My slideshow carousel doesn't work, I would like it to work manually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, carousel

I would like to create a carousel, my images are well-positioned but my carousel doesn't manually with the provided arrows, there might be some CSS properties which lack to my code. I don't kown if my javscript code is ok. I also would to style my arrows with CSS properties. Can please have a look at my code below.

http://placekitten.com/g/200/300

I am looking for a carousel that works manually, I would have liked it to be with autoplay but it's way to hard for me. I want that when the user clicks on the arrows, the slide changes and goes to the next slide. I would like that you check CSS and add some properties ( especially for the arrows but also the rest of the carousel). Could you also check the javascript I have introduced and correct it so that the carousel works.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
  const nextButton = document.querySelector('.carousel-button-next');
  const prevButton = document.querySelector('.carousel-button-prev');
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  let currentIndex = 0;


  function nextSlide() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % slides.length;
    updateCarousel();
  }

  function prevSlide() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + slides.length) % slides.length;
    updateCarousel();
  }

  function updateCarousel() {
    const offsetPercentage = -currentIndex * 100;
    carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${offsetPercentage}%)`;
  }

  nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
  prevButton.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-container .slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-container button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
}

.carousel-button-next {
  right: 32px;
}

.carousel-button-prev {
  left: 32px;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
}

.slide>img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-button:hover,
.carousel-button:focus {
  color: white;
}

.carousel-button:focus {
  outline: black 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="carousel-container" aria-label="Newest Photos">
    <div class="carousel"></div>
    <button class="carousel-button-prev">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="carousel-button-next">&#10095;</button>
    <ul>
      <li class="slide" data-active>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="woman developer">
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="web design">
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="workspace">
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="coding">
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please take more care in creating a [mcve] Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add images from for example lorem pixel of lorem kitten and change the HTML to be valid.

Comment: I clicked `[<>]` and added the code in the correct panes. You need to change your local pictures to something that works here for example from https://placekitten.com/

Comment: *"I would have liked it to be with autoplay but it's way to hard for me"* ... then why are you doing it if not for the challenge? Look around online for a suitable carousal library. There are hundreds. Query your search on the best.

Comment: Your title is a statement with a question mark stuck to the end (and a run-on sentence). Please see [ask], then revise it to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

To make it manual, add event listener to each slide element with forEach to iterate over the slides

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevButton.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

slides.forEach(function(slide, index) {
 slide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const direction = index > currentIndex ? 1 : -1;
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + direction + slides.length) % slides.length;
  updateCarousel();
  });
});
```

When a slide is clicked, it calculates the direction to move by comparing the clicked slide's index with the current index (currentIndex). Then, it updates the currentIndex accordingly to move to the next or previous slide based on the clicked slide's position. Finally, it calls the updateCarousel function to update the carousel's position based on the new currentIndex

However, if you want it automated, create a function (e.g. AutoPlay) that sets up an interval that calls the fucntion nextSlide every 5000m/s (change this value to your preference)

```
function AutoPlay() {
 intervalId = setInterval(nextSlide, 5000); // Adjust this
}
```

add another function that clears the interval, "pausing" the carousel

```
function stopAutoPlay() {
 clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

If you want the carousel to stop if you click on it, modify the event listeners to stop it

```
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    stopAutoPlay();
    nextSlide();
});

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    stopAutoPlay();
    prevSlide();
});
```

Finally, to automatically start the autoplay when the page loads, call Autoplay to begin automatic load

```
AutoPlay();
```

Comment: is it possible for you to have a look at my HTML and CSS code and give me feedback as you did, I think there might be some errors according to the javascript code which sounds good. Thanks à lot;

Comment: CSS looks good, maybe  break down the styles into smaller, more modular components for easier maintenance and reuse. If you want this to work on different screen sizes, think about using media queries. Overall, your HTML looks fine as far as I can see it,